# Need to skip or delete rc.local

Tags: boot-issues, noobs

I stuck some commands in my rc.local which cause the rpi to freeze (specifically, xboxdrv crashed and locks the pi up for some reason). I've even tried holding down ctrl+c throughout the xboxdrv part of the system booting, to no avail.

I can boot into recovery mode with NOOBS, and from there I can edit config.txt, cmdline.txt, and I can even get to a command line... but the primary partition isn't mounted as far as I can tell and I have no idea how to do that.
So I need to either make the booting skip rc.local, or edit rc.local (I'd even be fine with deleting rc.local).

Any ideas? I've googled this a bit, but frankly the things people have suggested were way over my head. I have little knowledge of Linux, and pretty much none of its boot process.

Comment: You do know that you can mount the SD card on your PC and change that file, don't you?

Comment: Not in Windows... the primary partition is ext4, and the only things I've found for that in Windows are read only, or else have scary warnings about potentially corrupting the file system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple approach is to get a PC with Linux (even a LiveCD distribution - [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) allows booting from CD for example) will suffice. Every modern Linux will recognize both SD partitions out of the box and allow you to modify their contents.

Comment: This is basically what I'm going to do... Gonna bring my sd card into work tomorrow and use a coworker's computer. We've got plenty of macs and linux boxes floating around here.

Comment: Note there *is* probably a way that involves plugging keyboard and screen to RPi and passing the right boot parameters (e.g. `init=/bin/bash`) to the kernel through the bootloader, but I have no clue how RPi bootloader works.